# Загрузка картинки с добавлением стикера

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Нужно подтянуть выбранную картинку, добавить на нее стикер, перетащив его на нужное место и сгенерировать из этого новую картинку, которая будет аватаром на сайте. Может есть скрипт с похожим функционалом?

Answer (score 1):

Есть похожий скрипт с генерацией каптчи. Ваша задача будет только в том, чтобы заменить $RandomCaptcha на ваш стикер, а фон на нужный вам аватар, ну и изменить соответственно координаты стикера и размеры полей.

```
$RandomCaptcha = rand(10001, 99999);
$_SESSION['captcha'] = md5($RandomCaptcha);
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(211, 40);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 211, 40, imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255));
imagettftext($im, 30, -5, 38, 30, imagecolorallocate($im, 82, 82, 82), 'captcha.ttf', $RandomCaptcha);
imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```